# How to write "{" in kendo grid template?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-template

I have a column in kendo grid that include template.

```
  {
        field: '["FileID"]',
        width: 100,
        title: "file",
        template: "<xi  control-url='FileManager/FilePreview/FilePreview'  
                   client-args={hideVisualization:true } />"
    }
```

but "{" in client-args has error.

unhandled rejection: {}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like client-args=({hideVisualization:true }).

Comment: no,client-args is a json object. I resolved it bythis : client-args=\'{ hideVisualization:true }\'

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by this 
 client-args=\'{ hideVisualization:true }\'